# How can I calculate the value passed as props from the style component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, prop

I want to dynamically control the position of style component 'top', 'left'. I want to calculate in that part, but I don't know how to do it.

```
    {contentsData.map((loc, idx) => {
              return (
                <LocationDisplay
                  width={width}
                  height={height}
                  locX={loc.locX}
                  locY={loc.locY}
                >
                  <LocationIdx>{idx + 1}</LocationIdx>
                </LocationDisplay>

<...>
<...>
<...>
const LocationDisplay = styled.div<{
  locX?: number | null
  locY?: number | null
  width?: number
  height?: number
}>`
  left: ${(props) => props.locX} + ${(props) => props.width} px;
  top: ${(props) => props.locY} + ${(props) => props.height}px; 
//This part does not work.*
```

Comment: I don't think what you show here is valid syntax. `left: ...` is outside any object.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways you can go about this...

first, you can put the props together...

```jsx
const LocationDisplay = styled.div<{
  locX?: number | null
  locY?: number | null
  width?: number
  height?: number
}>`
  left: ${props => props.locX + props.width}px;
  top: ${props => props.locY + props.height}px; 
  `
//  This part should work now. :)
```

or you can try this... adding the `calc()` function to the styled component, and passing the props inside of the equation.

```jsx
const LocationDisplay = styled.div<{
  locX?: number | null
  locY?: number | null
  width?: number
  height?: number
}>`
  left: calc(${props => props.locX}px + ${props => props.width}px);
  top: calc(${props => props.locY}px + ${props => props.height}px); 
  `
//  This part should work now. :)
```

**Explanation:**

> The `calc()` CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values. It can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<percentage>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is allowed.